# validating token issuer from Azure AD B2B

Tags: azure, token, bearer-token, azure-ad-b2b

Im trying to validate Access Token obtained from Azure AD B2B subs, Im using version 2   `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,`.

my current validation take place here in startup class

```
 services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.Audience = "application_id";
                o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id";
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, ValidateIssuer = true, ValidateAudience = true, ValidateLifetime = true };

            });
```

The token issuer is not validate

```
 www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"error_description="The issuer 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tanant_id/v2.0' is invalid"
```

the authorization URL

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tanant_id/oauth2/authorize
```

The scopes are being defined in Azure AD and used by the application.

```
 c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = uri,
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                             {
                                { "Access_api", "Admins and users" },
                             }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this?

Comment: Which doc did you refer to i.e. where is your code from?

Comment: Thanks @ikenahim and could you please makesure tenant id got populated with valid value and here are format of v1 and v2 (V1: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/token
 V2: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token)

Comment: tanant_id is stored in local variable and used

Comment: I will try using login.microsoftonline.com{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token , the tenant id is valid

Comment: After changing it i got this error while being authorized ```AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS requests. Received a GET request.```